# 'AVG' and 'Having Count' together?

Tags: sql

I have a test question I can't complete. It is as follows:

> App usage data are kept in the following table:

```
TABLE sessions
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   userId INTEGER NOT NULL,
   duration DECIMAL NOT NULL
```

> Write a query that selects userId and average session duration for each user who has more than one session.

I've tried the following which gives the answer but it still won't validate.

```
SELECT COUNT(userId), AVG(duration)
   FROM sessions
   GROUP BY userId
   HAVING COUNT(userId) > 1;
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: what do you mean by won't validate?

Comment: Im on a test website. The answers to test wont validate. Fourth question here https://www.testdome.com/d/sql-interview-questions/17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need this:

```
Select userId, AVG(duration)
From sessions 
Group By userId
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

```
SELECT userId, AVG(duration) 
FROM sessions
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT userId
   FROM sessions
   GROUP BY userId
   HAVING COUNT(userId) > 1);
```